# How to open url in android

Tags: android

**Please read my question first**

I want to open a URL in my app not in phone's browser.

You can see in Facebook or Twitter that how they open a Link in there own App.

**This will redirect to my phone's browser**

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

but I want to open URL like Facebook App.

Is there any specific API for this kind of view.

Comment: @Delta7 Are you Sure Facebook uses Webview?

Comment: [webview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: no , they made full app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs), check the link!

Here the basic example from the website

```
// Use a CustomTabsIntent.Builder to configure CustomTabsIntent.
// Once ready, call CustomTabsIntent.Builder.build() to create a CustomTabsIntent
// and launch the desired Url with CustomTabsIntent.launchUrl()

String url = ¨https://paul.kinlan.me/¨;
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: Hello appersiano, CustomTabsIntent class not found here.
Is there any library for CustomTabsIntent.

Comment: yes of course, check the implementation guide on the link, you can see the gradle depedency

Comment: Great man I am looking for the same.
Is there any way to give you 100 votes.

Thank you :)

Comment: @appersiano is it possible to open to http://... url customTabsIntent rather then https://..?

Answer (score 1):

Following code will help you to open the url in your app:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AppWebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview;
    private String mWebViewUrl;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);
        mWebViewUrl= getIntent().getStringExtra("web_view_url");

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl(mWebViewUrl);
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }

}
```

Define above activity in manifest like this:

```
 <activity
        android:name="<package-name>.AppWebViewActivity "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

And Add internet permission as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And to call this activity just follow below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AppWebViewActivity .class);
intent.putExtra("web_view_url", "your-complete-url");
startActivity(intent)
```

You can have custom ui in that case you have to define webview in xml and take the reference of layout in your webview activity.

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your time but Webview is not my solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can open url via webview within your app steps are below:

xml code below for webview;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.whiskey.servicedog.DocumentPlay"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_document_play">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

next code for java file below:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_document_play);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl(urlpath);
    }
```

hope this helps you out

Comment: Thanks for your time but Webview is not my solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use webview in a new activity to open url. https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score -1):

add a webview activity/fragment, and show website in webview.